# Is it safe to connect (select, update, insert) to Oracle database 10G with a 11G client?

Tags: database, oracle-10g, oracle-11g

I have to work in an Oracle 10G database. The normally used client is Oracle SQLDeveloper. But it has some limitations not related to the database use (Java versions on my PC, but that is another story). So I have to use another client.

DBeaver looks like a good candidate, but when configuring a database connection, the current version (3.5.8, zip without added Java) only has options for 11G or 12G.
There is a lot of info on the net about the differences, but not to such detail as to make it clear of backwards compatibility of 11G to 10G.

Is it safe to just choose the 11G and try it out on a 10G database? Seems too risky to me for update and insert, so probably here is someone already tried that. Or probably there is a possibility to get a 10G connection available in current DBeaver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the exact versions:

- *[Using 11g Client with 10g Database](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2382912?tstart=0)* says

  > "Metalink 207303.1 is the client/server interoperability matrix. If by 11g you mean 11.2 and by 10g you mean 10.1, the 11.2 client will not work with a 10.1 database. If the client is 11.2 and the database is 10.2, it should be at least 10.2.0.2. If the client is 11.1, the database should be 10.1.0.5 or 10.2.0.2 or higher."
- *[Is it ok to use oracle 11g client with a 10g server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454624/is-it-ok-to-use-oracle-11g-client-with-a-10g-server)* agrees with that (with less detail)